# ¿Por qué no decimos "ni mu"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, locuciones, animales

En la entrada del diccionario para *[mu](https://dle.rae.es/mu)* referido a la onomatopeya de la vaca encontramos la siguiente definición:

> **no decir ni mu**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. No decir palabra alguna, permanecer en silencio.

Me resulta curiosa esta expresión, sobre todo su origen. ¿Por qué se escogió el sonido de la vaca para este propósito? Podría haber sido "no decir ni guau" o "ni miau", o cualquier otra onomatopeya animal, pero se escogió "mu".

En diccionarios antiguos, la voz *mu* para el mugido del buey, vaca o toro se recoge al menos desde el *Autoridades* de 1734. Sin embargo, la primera vez que se recoge la expresión *ni mu* es en el *Academia manual* de 1984. No me imaginaba que la expresión fuera tan reciente, pensaba que sería más antigua. Veo efectivamente en el CORDE que el primer caso que se recoge es de 1956. Sin embargo, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España veo un caso mucho más antiguo:

> [...] finalmente parece que todos hemos de estar en adelante muy serios, sin decir ni *mu* ni *ma*.
>
> **El Amigo de las leyes**. 11/3/1814, n.º 24, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004958321&page=4&search=%22decir%20ni%20mu%22&lang=es).

Por tanto, la expresión se usaba ya a principios del siglo XIX, y es interesante, porque parece que lo de no decir "ni mu" podría provenir de una expresión más larga (que veo que aún se sigue usando). Y además me surge la siguiente duda: en algunos diccionarios definen la expresión "no decir ni mu" como "enmudecer", palabra que proviene de *[mudo](https://dle.rae.es/mudo)*, definida como "muy silencioso o callado", y que comparte la sílaba "mu" con la expresión, por lo que igual el "mu" de la expresión podría provenir de "mudo" (es tan mudo que no dice ni la "mu" de "mudo"). En cualquier caso, ¿cómo sabemos entonces que la expresión proviene del sonido de la vaca, y no de otro sitio? ¿Existe algún texto más antiguo que documente el uso de la expresión?

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por qué se escogió el sonido de la vaca para este propósito? Podría haber sido "no decir ni guau" o "ni miau", o cualquier otra onomatopeya animal, pero se escogió "mu".

Existe (al menos) otra formulación, de otro animal:

- [no decir (ni) pío](https://dle.rae.es/p%C3%ADo)

> ... parece que lo de no decir "ni mu" podría provenir de una expresión más larga...

Parece que estas son derivaciones de otras formas más antiguas, siguiendo la sintaxis `sin/no+Verbo+A+ni+B`:<sup>1</sup>

- no decir (ni) pío ni pa
- sin/no decir [tus ni mus](https://dle.rae.es/tus)
- sin/no decir [chuz ni muz](https://dle.rae.es/chuz) / [chus ni mus](https://dle.rae.es/chus)
- sin/no decir [oxte ni moxte](https://dle.rae.es/oxte) / oste ni moste

[image]

---

1. > Otra estructura recurrente son los binomios de formulación negativa del tipo
   > `ni+A+ni+B`, como vemos en *ni fu ni fa*, o del tipo `sin/no+Verbo+A+ni+B`, como *sin/no decir tus ni mus*, estructuras analizadas con mayor profundidad en [García-Page (2008: 338-340)](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Introducci%C3%B3n_a_la_fraseolog%C3%ADa_espa%C3%B1ol.html?id=WFnwOQAACAAJ).

   - [*«Neologismos fraseológicos» como palabras diacríticas
     en las locuciones en español*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/Lengua/paremia/pdf/021/005_aguilar.pdf) (2012)
2. En [Venezuela](https://www.significadode.org/ebook/68949-3.htm), también hay *no decir ni ñe*, con analogía a *no decir ni nada*.